# How to select one element from each column of a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
a = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3];

b = [1 2 3];
```

How can I call one function to get a vector `v[i] = a[b[i],i]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
v = a(sub2ind(size(a), b, 1:length(b)))
```

`sub2ind` transforms subscripts into a single index.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try, keeping very close to your description, you can use the `arrayfun` function.

First define a function that maps a value `x` to the desired output.

```
fn = @(x)  a(b(x), x);
```

Then call that function on each input in the the `i` vector.

```
i = 1:3;
v = arrayfun(fn, i);
```

Or, this can all be done in a single line, in the obvious way:

```
v = arrayfun(@(x)  a(b(x), x), 1:3);
```

This `arrayfun` is simply shorthand for the loop below:

```
for ixLoop = 1:3
    v(ixLoop) = a(b(ixLoop),ixLoop);
end
```

The related functions `arrayfun`, `cellfun`, and `structfun` have similar uses, and are strangely empowering.  [This Joel article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html) convinced me to be a believer.