# Select an element from each row of a matrix in R

Tags: r, vectorization

The question is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184090/how-to-select-one-element-from-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-matlab), but in R. I have a matrix  and a vector such that

```
length(vec) == nrow(mat)
```

How do i get a vector such that

```
v[i] == mat[v[i],i]
```

I tried to achieve this by using logical matrix:

```
>a = matrix(runif(12),4,3)
a
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.6077585 0.5354680 0.2802681
[2,] 0.2596180 0.6358106 0.9336301
[3,] 0.5317069 0.4981082 0.8668405
[4,] 0.6150885 0.5164009 0.5797668
> sel = col(a) == c(1,3,2,1)
> sel
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> a[sel]
[1] 0.6077585 0.6150885 0.4981082 0.9336301
```

It selects right elements but messes up the order. I thought of using `mapply` either, but i don't know how to make it iterate through rows, like in `apply`.

upd: @gsk3 suggested to use `as.list(as.data.frame(t(a)))` this works. But still i would like to know if there is a more vectorized way, without lists.

Comment: Use mapply by making a a list of vectors: as.list(as.data.frame(a))

Comment: This helps, except for rows you should do as.list(as.data.frame(t(a))), thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question, but it seems like this may be close?

```
> b=c(1,3,2,1)

> i=cbind(1:nrow(a),b)

> a[i]
```