# How do you access matrix element indicated by a vector

Tags: octave

If I have a *m x n* matrix **A**, and a *m x 1* vector **b** where each value is in [1, n]. Is there a trick to get [A(1, b(1), A(2, b(2), ...]?

A use case:

```
for i = 1 : 10
  A[i, b[i]] = A[i, b[i]] - 1;
end
```

Comment: m x n? I would expect a n x n squared matrix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select one element from each column of a matrix in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184090/how-to-select-one-element-from-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-matlab)

Comment: Am I interpreting correctly that `b` is any general vector of length `m` with each element having the value between 1 and n, inclusive, and in no particular order?

And in your question you ask for the output as a vector, but in the sample code it is a matrix.  what output are you looking for?  A full input/output example would make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly in your case is just a syntax error. Try out this:

```
for i = 1:10,
   A(i,b(i)) = A(i, b(i)) - 1; 
end;
```