# Is there a more elegant way to take values by indicies in 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to take values from a matrix by column indices in the array. My code works but it seems strange that i need to create dummy array.

EDIT: Scores is 500x10 matrix, y is a list of 500 indicies from 0 to 9. I have to select 500 values corresponding to y.

```
# scores: 2D matrix  
# y: array of indices

dummy_array = range(scores.shape[0])  
scores[range(dummy_array), y]
```

Comment: This is basic array indexing with numpy. Have you read the docs?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but it seems like you may want to read [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: Can you try explaining a bit your issue? hopefully you can provide a minimal example, the one you presented seems to be missing something.

Comment: This just a special case of indexing with 2 arrays `scores[x, y]`, with `x=np.arange(500)`.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand but is there a way to achive this result without creating np.arange(500)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a related question:

[How to index a ndarray with another ndarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451666/how-to-index-a-ndarray-with-another-ndarray)

```
a = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5) # Array to be indexed
b = np.arange(9, -1, -2) # Indexing array
```

Selecting one item from each column is done with:

```
In [252]: a[b, np.arange(5)]
Out[252]: array([45, 36, 27, 18,  9])
```

A similar action in MATLAB requires, [How to select one element from each column of a matrix in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184090/how-to-select-one-element-from-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-matlab), a `sub2ind` function which `unravels` the indices, producing a flat list:

```
a(sub2ind(size(a), b, 1:length(b)))
```

`numpy` has a similar function, constructing indices in to the 1d flatten (or ravelled) databuffer:

```
In [253]: np.ravel_multi_index((b, np.arange(5)), a.shape)
Out[253]: array([45, 36, 27, 18,  9])
In [254]: a.flat[_]
Out[254]: array([45, 36, 27, 18,  9])
```

Those `Out[253]` numbers are calculated with:

```
In [256]: b*5 + np.arange(5)
Out[256]: array([45, 36, 27, 18,  9])
```

So regardless of whether we provide the `np.arange(5)`, or just 5, or it is deduced from `a.shape`, the values are required to derive the flat indices.  Hiding that step isn't going to save you any time or memory.

Note that the order of those values is not regular, so it can't be expressed in terms of a slice.  In the more general case we are just picking points scattered at random around the array `a`.  They don't have to be one per row (or column), there could be several or none.

Here simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.  To me the idea indexing with

```
a[x, y]
```

where `x` and `y` can be any arrays that are broadcastable is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
l = [j[y[i]] for i, j in enumerate(scores)]
```

`l` is your 500 length list.

But also `numpy.arange()` as said in the comments works.

Comment: Range can be used for indexing, it gives the same result as numpy.arange().

Comment: You're right. I tried before writing this answer, but got an error. Maybe I did something wrong that time. I'll remove the incorrect part.