# How to index a ndarray with another ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing some machine learning stuff in python/numpy in which I want to index a 2-dimensional ndarray with a 1-D ndarray, so that I get a 1-D array with the indexed values.

I got it to work with some ugly piece of code and I would like to know if there is a better way, because this just seems unnatural for such a nice language and module combination as python+numpy.

```
   a = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5) # Array to be indexed
   b = np.arange(9, -1, -2) # Indexing array
   print(a)
   print(b)
   print(a[b, np.arange(0, a.shape[1]).reshape(1,a.shape[1])])
   #Prints:
   [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
    [ 5  6  7  8  9]
    [10 11 12 13 14]
    [15 16 17 18 19]
    [20 21 22 23 24]
    [25 26 27 28 29]
    [30 31 32 33 34]
    [35 36 37 38 39]
    [40 41 42 43 44]
    [45 46 47 48 49]]

   [9 7 5 3 1]

   [[45 36 27 18  9]]
```

This is exactly what I want(even though technically a 2-D ndarray), but this seems very complicated. Is there a neater and tidier way?

Edit:
To clarify, I actually I do not want a 1-D array, that was very poorly explained. I actually do want one dimension with length 1, because that is what I need for processing it later, but this would be easily achieved with a `reshape()` statement. Sorry for the confusion, I just mixed my actual code with the more general question.

Comment: Why did you perform the `reshape` if you want a 1D array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a 1D array, yet you included a `reshape` call whose only purpose is to take the array from the format you want to a format you don't want.

Stop reshaping the `arange` output. Also, you don't need to specify the `0` start value explicitly:

```
result = a[b, np.arange(a.shape[1])]
```

Comment: Alright, this seems like the best one can do. Accepted as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `np.diagonal` to get what you want. No need of `reshape` or indexing. The tricky part here was to identify the pattern which you want to obtain which is basically the diagonal elements of `a[b]` matrix.

```
a = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5) # Array to be indexed
b = np.arange(9, -1, -2) # Indexing array
print (np.diagonal(a[b]))
# [45 36 27 18  9]
```

As @user2357112 mentioned in the comments, the return of `np.diagonal` is read only. In my opinion, it would be a problem if you plan to append/modify the values to this final desired list. If you just want to print them or use them for some further indexing, it should be fine.

As per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)

> Starting in NumPy 1.9 it returns a read-only view on the original array. Attempting to write to the resulting array will produce an error.
>
> In some future release, it will return a read/write view and writing to the returned array will alter your original array. The returned array will have the same type as the input array.
>
> **If you don’t write to the array returned by this function, then you can just ignore all of the above.**

Comment: That performs a lot of extra data copying, keeps the whole `a[b]` in memory, and produces a read-only array.

Comment: @user2357112: Can you explain please the "produces a read-only" part again?

Comment: @user2357112: Do you mean first storing `a[b]` in some variable and then passing it to np.diagonal?

Comment: [The return value of `np.diagonal` is a non-writable view.](https://ideone.com/XJn1Gc)

Comment: @user2357112: So you mean one cannot edit or append or modify the array returned? But if the OP don't plan to use it for further post processing but just wants to get the result and print it let's say, then the non-writable view is not a problem. Am I right?

Comment: Aside from some weird edge cases (for example, I think Cython doesn't play well with read-only arrays, because it asks for a read-write memoryview even if it doesn't need one), the non-writability isn't a problem if you don't plan to write to it. The other problems are still problems.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for the heads up. I acknowledged your comments in my answer for awareness